# Align text center and vertically

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

in bootstrap if i use the class `text-center` i get something like

```
                              aaaaaaaa
                            aaaaaaaaaaaa
                               aaaaaa
```

and if i use `text-left` i get

```
aaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaa
```

but what if i wanted the following

```
                            aaaaaaaa
                            aaaaaaaaaaaa
                            aaaaaa
```

i am not sure what this is exactly called and how can i achieve it, any ideas?

Comment: Consider using the bootstrap column model to place the entire block horizontally while still keeping the text left-aligned.

Comment: Was just about to say what @dlev did. Basically, just put them inside of a  `<div class="col-lg-YOURWIDTH col-lg-offset-YOUROFFSET text-left">…</div>` and they will be justified left with a margin to the left.

Comment: @Luxelin thank you that worked perfectly i used col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-6 text-left, feel free to add an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Bootstrap's built-in grid system:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 text-left">
    <p>aaaaaaa</p>
    <p>aaa</p>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaa</p>
</div>
```

This will center the block while keeping the text flushed left to the invisible margin. The basic rule is to use `col-lg-X` and `col-lg-offset-X/2` for your classes; this will ensure the div is centered. You need to manually (or programmatically) type `X`. Using what I typed obviously won't work.